# MySQL query sometimes deadlocks

Tags: mysql, go, concurrency

I'm working on a program that makes a query to MySQL, then for each row, changes something with that row and then update the row.

The problem is that sometimes when performing an update I get a deadlock, I'm not sure if it's because the query isn't releasing the lock by the time I update or if it's something else.

Example of what I'm doing:

```
const (
    selectQuery = `select user_id, original_transaction_id, max(payment_id) as max_payment_id from Payment_Receipt 
                        where auto_renew_status = 1 group by user_id, original_transaction_id having count(*) > 1`
    updateQuery = `update Payment_Receipt set auto_renew_status = 0, changed_by = "payment_receipt_condenser", 
changed_time = ? where user_id = ? and original_transaction_id = ? and payment_id != ? and auto_renew_status = 1`
)
```

mysql.go:

```
func New(db *sql.DB, driver string) (database.Database, error) {
    sqlDB := sqlx.NewDb(db, driver)

    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "connecting to database")
    }

    selectStmt, err := sqlDB.Preparex(selectQuery)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "preparing select query")
    }

    updateStmt, err := sqlDB.Preparex(updateQuery)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "preparing update query")
    }

    return &mysql{
        db:         sqlDB,
        selectStmt: selectStmt,
        updateStmt: updateStmt,
    }, nil
}

func (m *mysql) Query() (<- chan *database.Row, error) {
    rowsChan := make(chan *database.Row)

    rows, err := m.selectStmt.Queryx()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "making query")
    }

    go func() {
        defer rows.Close()
        defer close(rowsChan)

        for rows.Next() {
            row := &database.Row{}

            if err := rows.StructScan(row); err != nil {
                log.WithError(err).WithField("user_id", row.UserID.Int32).Error("scanning row")
            }

            // change some of the data here
            // and put into channel for worker to consume

            rowsChan <- row
        }
    }()

    return rowsChan, nil
}

func (m *mysql) Update(row *database.Row) error {
    tx, err := m.db.Beginx()
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "beginning transaction")
    }

    if _, err := tx.Stmtx(m.updateStmt).Exec(row.ChangedTime); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "executing update")
    }

    if err := tx.Commit(); err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "committing transaction")
    }

    return nil
}
```

worker.go

```
func (w *worker) Run(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    rowsChan, err := w.db.Query()
    if err != nil {
        log.WithError(err).Fatal("failed making query")
    }

    for i := 0; i < w.config.Count(); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for row := range rowsChan {
                if err := w.db.Update(row); err != nil {
                    log.WithError(err).WithField("user_id", row.UserID.Int32).Error("updating row")
                }
            }
        }()
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect during the `w.db.Update()` calls the initial query is still generating rows - and that is the source of the deadlock. A simple "bandaid" fix would be to make the (rows) channel buffered.

Comment: For clarity can you confirm that you are getting a MySQL deadlock (as opposed to a goroutine deadlock). If so please share selectQuery & updateQuery.

Comment: @Brits yes I can confirm that it is a MySQL deadlock. I'm getting: `Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction" user_id=2491427`. I have edited the post to include the queries.

Comment: Thanks; I'm a little confused about your ```update``` statement (it has 4 parameter markers but you only pass it one value ```tx.Stmtx(m.updateStmt).Exec(row.ChangedTime)```). Assuming I'm missing something re the paramaters the next step is to confirm the cause of the deadlock (otherwise we are really guessing); running ```SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS``` is the simplest approach (see [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks-handling.html) for an explanation and other options).

Answer (score 0):

You could make the results (row) channel from a `Query()` buffered:

```
func (m *mysql) Query() (<- chan *database.Row, error) {

    rowsChan := make(chan *database.Row, 1000) // <- band-aid fix

    // ...
}
```

This will ensure that the row collector function can write multiple results without waiting for your worker go-routine to read the results. The query operation will complete (provided there are 1000 rows or less), and the update go-routine operations can begin their parallel work.

If this fixes things, then consider putting say an `SQL` limit on your queries (e.g. `LIMIT 1000`) to ensure you don't hit deadlock again (if 1000+ records is a real possibility).

Crafting "pagination" style queries to grab the next say 1000 rows, using RowID markers etc. to ensure full coverage of results - all while avoiding locking out any of your `update` operations.

Comment: So I tried that, I set the size of the channel to `w.config.Count()` which was set to 10 so there would be 10 workers and the channel size would also be 10 and I ran into the same error.


Or did you mean create a buffered channel but only return once `rows.Next()` returns `false`?

Comment: Just edited answer. I suspect the deadlock is when the first worker reads the first row from the results-channel and tries to do a `db.Update()` - all while the Query() function is trying to write the next row result. Adding a buffer to the results channel allows the initial query complete - and thus eliminate one shared resource deadlock possibility.